# React ChildrenArray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Can someone tell me as to how `childrenarray` of [flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-childrenarray) is used in practice ?

What design pattern benefits do we get from using this instead of just using a standard array declaration in javascript.

```
const children: React.ChildrenArray<number> = 42;

const children: React.ChildrenArray<number> = [[1, 2], 3, [4, 5]];
```

https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-childrenarray

Answer (score 1):

`ChildrenArray` represents a special React type used in the [React Children API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren).  It is explicitly *not* a JavaScript `Array`.  From [a blog post describing these types](https://medium.com/flow-type/even-better-support-for-react-in-flow-25b0a3485627):

> React.ChildrenArray is the type for the React children data
>   structure. React children are not a simple array: they could be a
>   single value or an arbitrarily nested array. React.ChildrenArray
>   allows you to model the data structure and cleanly interoperate with
>   the React.Children API, which is typed in Flow 0.53.0.